# how could I obtain the user input from a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I have this layout for a dialog. When factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null); is called, how can i get the user input from editText when its root layout is inflated?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/username_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="@string/alert_dialog_username"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_edit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="@string/alert_dialog_password"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:password="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**How to obtain the username from the user input and do sth in the onClick() method below?**

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
        .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
        .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .create();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
EditText et = (EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
Log.d("TAG", ev.getText());
```

As you already made the `textEntryView` final this should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Get EditText like this:

```
 EditText userName=(EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
```

And in PositiveButton Click listener,get the value of EditText;

userName.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
EditText userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourinputid);
String input = userInput.getText().toString();
```

Comment: You forgot to cast the `View` to `EditText`.